# Opencv как распознать фигуру и найти координаты его части?

Tags: python, opencv

Я собираюсь составить скрипт для решения капчи слайдера, я хотел спросить, есть рисунок с капчей (рис 1,2) на котором явно присутствует фигура пазла (которая черная), как распознать эту фигуру, и найти координаты ее части, конкретно части круга пазла. Фон капчи каждый раз меняется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]